# Can if let be comma-separated in Swift 3.1?

Tags: swift, if-statement

In the [Implement Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html) chapter of the Start [Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift) tutorial by Apple, there is a following code snippet:

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController,
   meal = sourceViewController.meal {}
```

This tutorial uses Swift 3.1 and this snippet doesn't seem to work for me. It works only if I prepend `meal = sourceViewController.meal` with `let` keyword as well, like this:

```
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController,
   let meal = sourceViewController.meal {}
```

The origin of my question is pure curiosity: has `if let a = b, c = d` ever been valid syntax in any Swift version?

Comment: Your final question and your question's title don't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the following code compiles with Xcode 8 and "legacy mode" (i.e.
Swift 2.3):

```
let a: Int? = 1
let b: Int? = 2

if let x = a, y = b { }
```

Starting with Swift 3 it has to be written as

```
if let x = a, let y = b { }
```

as a consequence of [SE-0099 Restructuring Condition Clauses](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md), in particular (emphasis added):

> The root problem lies in the condition grammar: commas are used both to separate items within a clause (e.g. in `if let x = a, y = b {`) and to separate mixed kinds of clauses (e.g. `if let x = a, case y? = b {`). This proposal resolves this problem by retaining commas as separators between clauses (as used elsewhere in Swift) and **limits clauses to single items.**

Comment: So it seems like this tutorial has been written prior to Swift 3 and they forgot to update this line. Am I right?

Comment: @RoboRobok: Actually most of it looks like Swift 3 code, e.g. value types like `IndexPath` were introduced in Swift 3. So it seems to be just an oversight when updating the sample code.